# Instant resumption after hibernation

Tags: arch-linux, macintosh, hibernate

My Macbook Air with Arch has suddenly begun to resume instantly after hibernation, so that I have to hold down the power button at the boot menu to get it powered off.  Apart from that, hibernation works as before.  What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

I had commented out the line

```
echo LID0 >/proc/acpi/wakeup
```

in `/etc/rc.local`.